# Login into php website and automatically get logged in into Drupal website running on different server?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, single-sign-on

My comapny has a web portal written in php and mysql and there is another website running in Drupal-7 so they want me to integreate SSO i:e; once someone login into portal he/she should be automatically logged into drupal website by clicking the website link(drupal website) from the portal. is there any way to do it?

**Note:** I don't have any idea about Drupal system.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a the code that handles the user login post it here.
Basically you need to act on user login somewhere in the code, and make a curl request to the drupal site api to login there too.
A good starting point is to learn about the [Services module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services).
Also read [Making authenticated requests to REST Server](https://www.drupal.org/node/910598)

Comment: Mostly i code in php and it frameworks. No any experiece in Drupal so what i am thinking is to pass username from php website to Drupal and check the user, if it exists then create the session to bypass login. I'm trying to write some raw php code on drupal website to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to make Drupal 7 Users table common for both the sites.

For this you need to do migration of users as well as change the code in PHP site at registration and login to use Drupal 7 Rest API to get login and resister into the portal.

Comment: Keeping users same in both DB was in mind too. Next procedure i am thinking about to pass username to drupal website with some security keys to check user exist. If user exists then i will create a session on druapal website to skip login and for that i am thining about writing some raw php code on druapal website to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) (SSP) is a very good solution for you to look at. It provides a SAML 2.0 [service provider](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp) (SP) and [identity provider](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp) (IdP) in one package.

You would need to set up SSP as an Identity Provider first, for which you could use a simple MySQL database for the users. Then, you can connect both the portal, and Drupal with the Identity Provider via SAML integration, where here the portal and the Drupal site will be "service providers".

If you install SSP on the site with the portal, I don't think that it can function as both the IdP and SP, fair warning. You would need to either use an alternative SAML service provider (like [Shibboleth](https://www.shibboleth.net/products/service-provider/)), or better yet, second instance of under a different hostname. (Otherwise the cookies will conflict.)  You will also need to integrate Drupal, which could be easily done with a [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplesamlphp_auth).

If you wanted to go the other way, where to Drupal site's user's table is used as an authentication source, that's doable as well using SimpleSAMLphp along with [drupalauth4ssp](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalauth4ssp) Drupal module in conjunction with the [drupalauth](https://github.com/drupalauth/simplesamlphp-module-drupalauth) SSP module.